# How to attach a linear layout inside preference screen so that entire screen is scrollable together?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I want to add a linear layout as a child to a layout with preferencescreen as root element, so that this is linear layout is scrolled together with elements in the preferencescreen just like scrolling in a single scrollview.

Comment: I'd just try using a PreferenceFragment (static fragment http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html ), and place whatever else you need under it, and this into a vertical LinearLayout. Unless your usecase is actually more complicated.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce.. i want to add that linear layout dynamically.. there are so many other screens which have preferencescreen as the root element of layout.. and when i'm adding it, only part of it is scrollable. i mean linear layout is stuck at the top and not scrolled up